# Bad Request Invalid CSRF Token. odoo PHP

Tags: php, routes, odoo

I want to create and manage databases Odoo from my website.  So I have this error:

```
Bad Request

Invalid CSRF Token.
```

So to resolve this problem, please, can you help me?  How do I do this in Odoo:

- if the form is accessed by an external third party (e.g. REST API
  endpoint, payment gateway callback) you will need to disable CSRF
  protection (and implement your own protection if necessary) by
  passing the `csrf=False` parameter to the `route` decorator.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this you will need to change `csrf` parameter in controller definition. For example:

```
@http.route(['/payment/authorize/return/',], type='http', auth='public', csrf=False)
    def authorize_form_feedback(self, **post):
```

So when you try to submit a form on that `route` you won't need `csrf_token`.